# newline character read twice

Tags: c++, char, newline

I am writing a tokenizer for one of my classes, but I'm having a problem when reading the files.

On an input like this for example:

```
00 'this has a  
01 Return  
02 The end''s near
```

This is the expected output:

```
(UNDEFINED,"'this has a  
Return  
The end''s near  
",1)
```

But this is the output I'm getting:

```
(UNDEFINED,"'this has a  
Return  
The end''s near  

",1)
```

This is the part of the code that reads that:

```
void readString(int& lineNumber, vector<Token*>& tokenList, ifstream& in)
{
char symbol;
int startingLineNumber = lineNumber;
string comment = "\'";
in.get(symbol);
do {

    switch (symbol) {
        case '\n':
            lineNumber++;
            comment += symbol;
            symbol = ' ';
            break;
        case '\'':
            if (in.peek() == '\'') {
                comment += symbol;
                in.get(symbol);
                comment += symbol;
            }
            else
            {
                comment += symbol;
                Token *newToken = NULL;
                newToken = new Token("STRING", comment, startingLineNumber);
                tokenList.push_back(newToken);
                return;
            }
            break;
        default:
            comment += symbol;
    }
} while (in.get(symbol));
readUndefined(comment, startingLineNumber, tokenList);
}
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me figure out why that's happening.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there's a reason to pass an `fstream` to the function, a plain `istream` should suffice. Then, you can use a stringstream in order to finish the required minimal example or write actual unit tests for this function.

Answer (score 0):

`do...while` is wrong!
you should convert `do...while` to `while` and check `first symbol` out of loop, or check `last symbol` and `break` from loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by first symbol and last symbol?